# Select Top for Subquery with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a Master-Detail model relationship set up in C# Entity Framework.  One Master record might have multiple Detail records.  I wish to bring back ALL Master records but only the first associated Detail record per Master record.

e.g.
Master:  Id=5

Detail:  Id=1; EventMasterId=5;

Detail:  Id=2; EventMasterId=5;

Detail:  Id=3; EventMasterId=5;

When "Master Id 5" comes back, I only want the first associated record "Detail Id 1". I don't want the other details.

I can do this in raw SQL but can't figure out how to convert this to LINQ:

```
SELECT * FROM EventMasters
JOIN EventDetails
ON EventDetails.Id =
  (SELECT TOP 1 Id
    FROM EventDetails
    WHERE EventMasterId=EventMasters.Id
    ORDER BY StartDate)
```

It's the "Select Top 1" from the EventDetails that's especialy tripping me.

Would anyone know how to convert this SQL statement to LINQ please?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Masters
   .Select(m => new{
       Master = m, 
       Detail = m.Details.OrderBy(d => d.StartDate).FirstOrDefault())
   })
```

Comment: Thank you @spender. You made it look so easy! Thanks again and happy new year.